# C++ display super palindromes

Tags: c++, loops

I need to display palindromes and squares of those palindromes has to be palindromes as well(for example, 11 is palindrome and its square 121 is also a palindrome). using c++, loops.
This is what i have so far(this outputs just palindromes):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n, r, atv, temp;

    for(n = 0; n <= 100; ++n){
        temp = n;
        atv = 0;

        while(temp){
            r = temp % 10;
            temp = temp / 10;
            atv = atv * 10 + r;
        }

        if(n == atv){
            cout << n << '\n';
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post you code in text instead of an image.

Comment: You know how to tell if a number is a palindrome, so you can use the same technique to tell if a number that was obtained by squaring another number is a palindrome; do you not know how to square a number?

Comment: That's a start, but it lacks a question. Go on to the next step, and come back when you have a specific question to ask? At this point, I would just mention that coding is easier when you divide your problem into pieces and write a function for each piece.

Comment: Manipulating or accessing digits of a number may be easier when the number is a string, e.g. `int digit = text[i] - '0';`

Comment: Create a function that checks a string or number as palindrome.  Call it for the original number and also for the square of the number.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna go ahead and assume that your own code confuses you and adding another layer of the same would make the code unreadable.
To fix this, we can introduce a function that checks whether a number is a palindrome.

```cpp
bool is_palindrome(const int num){
    int reversed_num = 0;
    int temp = num;

    while(temp){
        int last_num = temp % 10;
        temp /= 10;

        reversed_num = reversed_num * 10 + last_num;
    }

    return num == reversed_num;
}
```

We can also make this function much more readable by using `std::string`.

```cpp
bool is_palindrome(const int num){
    string original = to_string(num);

    return original == string(rbegin(original), rend(original));
}
```

In the latter, we use reverse `begin` and `end` iterators to construct the same, but reversed string.

Now, your code looks much cleaner and more readable.

```cpp
int main(){
    for(int num = 0; num <= 1000; ++num){
        if(is_palindrome(num) && is_palindrome(num * num)){
            cout << num << '\n';
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i need to complete this without using functions